# Computational examples in differential geometry using Mathematica, Matlab, Maple etc. with visualization possible

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, matlab, maple, mathematica

I want to master the computing "apparatus" of differential geometry. Some theoretical sections are already very difficult to assimilate, and without visual calculations it is almost impossible to understand more complex sections for an unprepared person.
I ask suggest literature that specializes in specific computational examples, and which could be tried in the indicated software packages and, if possible, visualized.

Comment: Thank you! I need some beginner level example of calculation.

Comment: For me, this is a whole new level of computing.
It’s very difficult to understand without qualified support.
I hope this book helps me.

Comment: If you understand the geometric theory of control, then tell me how to use this book to understand this section too.

Comment: I will ask the question differently: are there books of the same type on the geometric control theory (not just a theory, but computational experiments for clarity)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98976/discussion-between-andy-sol-and-moo).